# LODS from FS (MASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, opcodes

I wish to use the LODS opcode to load a double byte from FS to eax.
The default segment that is used with LODS is the DS, I wish to override that with FS.
How can this be done using MASM opcodes ?

```
00000000 (02) 6a30                     PUSH 0×30
00000002 (01) 5e                       POP ESI
00000003 (02) 64ad                     LODS EAX, [FS:ESI]
```

Source from here http://www.ragestorm.net/blogs/?p=369

Thanks alot,
Michael Engstler

Answer (score 3):

1) In the future, please remember to post a code snippet, if possible.  It's always helpful :)

2) The 16-bit, real mode LODS* instructions *always* assume DS , ES and AX.  You can't change this.

3) If you wish to use FS, you might also need the "ASSUME NOTHING" directive. For example:

```
ASSUME FS:NOTHING
MOV EAX, FS:[0]
ASSUME FS:ERROR
```

'Hope that helps .. PSM

PS:
If you just want to learn assembler, I'd strongly encourage you to try 32-bit protected mode.  Here is an excellent resource, if you're interested:

- [Programming from the Ground Up, Jonathan Bartlett](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, The problem with mov eax, fs:[0] is that it is translated to: 64 A1 00 00 00 00 .. This opcode contains NULL bytes and is no good for me .. Therefore I need a way to load data from the FS segment without creating null bytes in my code, The answer for my problem was to use LODS using the code snippet I just added.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer.

```
lods dword ptr fs:[esi]
```